# Css animation not working with custom variables

Tags: css

I have 3 questions
**Q.1 this animation is not woking**
This is the code

```css
@property --a {
  syntax: '<angle>';
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: 90deg;
}
button {
  --a: 40deg;
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 101px;
  background: black;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: white;
  transition:--a 0.5s;
  animation: anim 500ms linear infinite;
}
button::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: -5px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  z-index: -1;
  filter:blur(4px);
  background: linear-gradient(var(--a), red, blue);
}


@keyframes anim {
  100% {
    --a: 360deg;
  }
}
```

```html
<button>btn</button>
```

**Q.2 What is the meaning of this**

```
transition:--a 0.5s 0.1s;
```

**Q.3 why this doesn't work when applying this on the above css code**

```
transition:all 0.5s;
```

Comment: One question at a time, please. [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Since `--a` is only implemented in `button` so either you have to change `animation` to `:after` or you have to inherit `--a` like this:

```css
@property --a {
  syntax: '<angle>';
  inherits: true;
  initial-value: 90deg;
}
button {
  --a: 40deg;
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 101px;
  background: black;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: white;
  transition:--a 0.5s;
  animation: anim 500ms linear infinite;
}
button::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: -5px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  z-index: -1;
  filter:blur(4px);
  background: linear-gradient(var(--a), red, blue);
}


@keyframes anim {
  100% {
    --a: 360deg;
  }
}
```

```html
<button>btn</button>
```

2. It's a quick CSS `transition` syntax to specify `duration` and `delay` at the same time.
3. `transition` makes no sense when together with `animation` because `animation` applies its own function

Comment: But I didn't understood the 3rd one

Comment: read on mozilla there are few properties that `transition` must not interfere and `animation` is one of them